# Variance of gaussian using MLE approach

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood

Using the MLE approach to estimate the variance of the best fit gaussian [like in this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/maximum-likelihood-estimation-explained-normal-distribution-6207b322e47f), we reach the formula:

$$-\frac{n}{\sigma}+\frac1{\sigma^3}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2=0$$

We then multiply both sides by sigma and find the solution, however doesn't multiply by sigma eliminate a solution? In this case $1/\sigma = 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution at +inf is a minimum

Answer (score 2):

The parameter $\sigma$ is generally taken to be finite, so the outcome $1/\sigma = 0$ is not admissible.  (If you take the limit to an infinite variance, your distribution approaches a uniform distribution on the reals, which is not a proper distribution, so you would need to think about what distribution you actually have in that case.)  From the score equation, multiplying both sides by $\sigma^3$ gives:

$$ - n \cdot \sigma^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = 0.$$

Re-arranging then gives the MLE:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the article, this equation is reached by $\nabla_\sigma\log L(\mathcal{X})=0$, where $L(\mathcal{X})$ is the likelihood of the data. You multiply each side by $\sigma$ assuming it's a real number satisfying $\sigma>0$. Actually, while taking derivatives, and taking logarithms (e.g. $\log \sigma^2$), you've already made the same assumption.

Comment: But plus infinity is still greater than 0

Comment: but plus inf is not a real number